# How to get the parent value from xtemplate

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Does any one know how can i get the id_produs value ?

This is the code

```
 var tplv_cos = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="thumb_cos" id="{id_produs}">',
            '<div align="right" class="tpl-add-button"></div>',
            '<br>',
              '<img src = "imagini/{imagine}" id="ttt">',
              '<br>',
              '<b>{denumire}</b>',
              '<br>',
              '<b>Pret : {pret}</b>',
              '<div id="id_dv_txtf" style="width: 16%" class="comment-add-textfield"></div>',
             '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
    {
        compiled:true
    }); 

    var view_cos = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', { 
         id:    'idv_cos',
         itemSelector:'div.tpl-add-button',
         renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
         store: store_view_cos,
         tpl: tplv_cos,
         listeners: {
             refresh:function(){
                var renderSelector = Ext.query('div.comment-add-textfield'); 
                    for(var i in renderSelector){
                        Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',{
                            value: 1,
                            renderTo:renderSelector[i],
                              listeners: {
                                    change: function(c, node){
                                        alert(Ext.query('div.thumb_cos')[0])
                                    //this.getValue(c)
```

Here I need the id_produs value for the current text field

Here I get the changed value but I can't send the data to the server because I don't have a valid id
Can someone give me a hint ?

```
                        }
                            }
                });   
            }
            var renderSelector1 = Ext.query('div.tpl-add-button'); 
            for(var j in renderSelector1){
                Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
                    text: 'X',
                    renderTo:renderSelector1[j]
                });   
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[XTemplate API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/Ext.XTemplate.html#ext-xtemplate_template-member-functions)

I think this useful;

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<p>Name: {name}</p>',
'<p>Kids: ',
'<tpl for="kids">',
    '<tpl if="this.isGirl(name)">',
        '<p>Girl: {name} - {age}</p>',
    '<tpl else>',
        '<p>Boy: {name} - {age}</p>',
    '</tpl>',
    '<tpl if="this.isBaby(age)">',
        '<p>{name} is a baby!</p>',
    '</tpl>',
'</tpl></p>',
{
    // XTemplate configuration:
    disableFormats: true,
    // member functions:
    isGirl: function(name){
       return name == 'Aubrey' || name == 'Nikol';
    },
    isBaby: function(age){
       return age < 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 listeners: {
            scope: this,
            itemclick: function (record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                console.log(item.data.id_produs);                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)